# How to know if an expression is a solution to a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, education

I have to very simple question, that I am having some trouble with.

I am given an inhomogeneous linear system over $\mathbb{R}$ with four rows and three columns. We know that $v_p$ is a particular soloution.The question is then, is $2 \cdot v_p$ also a soloution?[$v_p \quad expression$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVr8V.png)

I have already made some thoughts my self, but I would like to hear your thoughts.

**EDIT:**

Initially my thought was that $2 \cdot v_p$ is not a solution, because, if we have $A \cdot v_p = B$ we cant also have $A \cdot 2 \cdot v_p = B$

**EDIT 2:**
It is a inhomogeneous, not homogeneous

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @DietrichBurde i have made an update

Comment: Do you know what "homogeneous system" means?

Comment: Maybe try to find an explicit counterexample if you don't think the answer is true! Also \mathbb{R} will produce the symbol for the real numbers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, but i wrote it wrong it is a inhomogeneous system

Comment: @Womm thanks, I will try it

Comment: You equation should be $A\cdot v_p=b$, where $b\in \Bbb R^3$. Usually $B$ is a square matrix. After your edit, where is your doubt now? I don't see any question.

Comment: I just dont know how to explain it properly. Meaning, how to exlpain that it is not also a soloution @DietrichBurde

Comment: It is necessary to give an explicit counterexample. Find such a system which has solution $v_p$ but not $2v_p$. This is easy. But you need to start doing it. Remember, four rows and three columns. They can contain some $0$ as entries.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks for the help i will try it out

Answer (score 0):

$\quad$ There are only three cases for a linear systems of $Ax=b$: there are no solutions, there are unique solutions, and there are infinitely many solutions.

$\quad$ Since we already know a particular solution $v$, it can't be the first case. For the others, we can combine the discussion (if there is only a unique solution, then the subspace $X$ in the following article is interpreted as a $0$-dimensional subspace $\{0\}$).

$\quad$ So, you should know that the solution of $Ax=b$ has the range $X+a$, where $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$($n$ is the number of columns in matrix $A$), and $X+a$ represents the set of every element in $X$ to which a constant $a$ is added. Here $a$ can be a particular solution for any of the linear systems. Since the linear systems is inhomogeneous, $a$ is not an element of $X$ (otherwise $X+a=X$, which means $0$ is a solution, which means that there must be $b=0$ in the linear systems $Ax=b$, which means the linear systems is homogeneous).

$\quad$ We know that for any element $x_0$ of a subspace $X$, $2x_0$ is also a member of that space. So if $v$ is an element of $X+a$, then there is an element $x$ of $X$ such that $x+a=v$, so $2v=2x+2a$. Suppose, $2v$ is also an element of $X+a$, then $2x+a$ must be an element of $X$, and since $2x$ is already an element of $X$, $a$ must be an element of $X$. There's a contradiction!

$\quad$ In summary, for a inhomogeneous linear systems with any row and any column, $2v$ must not be a solution as long as $v$ is a particular solution.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the explanation, I will definitely look into it